# how to call another function from a different file using eval in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, getscript

so basically i have an app.js file which has a function which will pass a parameter

and i have more js files like posts.js, comment.js
then i can do app.init('posts');

then i find the file, get it using getscript, but now i need to call the file.

here is my code

```
init:function(file){
        getfile = file;
        if($.inArray(getfile+'.js', modular_array)!==-1){
              $.getScript("js/modulars/"+getfile+'.js', function(data){
                  console.log(eval(getfile)["init"]); // this does not! why
                  //console.log(posts.init()); // this works
              });
        } else {
            console.log('not it');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) loads and runs the script file automatically - you don't need to manually execute it:

```
init:function(file){
        getfile = file;
        if($.inArray(getfile+'.js', modular_array)!==-1){
              $.getScript("js/modulars/"+getfile+'.js');
        } else {
            console.log('not it');
        }
    }
```

If you do want to call some initialization function defined by the script, you can call it directly, as you discovered: `posts.init()`

The code `eval(getfile)` does not work because `getfile` is a filename.  `eval` needs a string containing Javascript code.